# How Can I install multiple cronjobs using helm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a cronjob file in helm that looks like the below:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: job-1
  namespace: default
  ...
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: job-2
  namespace: default
  ...
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: job-3
  namespace: default
  ...
```

How do I install all cronjobs with their names as job-1, job-2 and job-3 using just one helm install command: `helm install $name $chart`

I tried installing it and it only installs job-1. I was expecting it to install all three jobs and when I run `kubectl get cronjobs` I should be able to see all three jobs

Answer (score 1):

Put each CronJob in a separate file in the `templates` directory.

In principle it is also possible to split this into separate YAML documents, but this isn't usually a preferred approach.  (It's necessary if you use the Helm template `range` construct to create multiple documents using a loop, though.)  Put `---` on its own line before each document.

```yaml
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: job-1
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: job-2
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: job-3
```

Without these markers, this is taken as a single mapping with duplicated `key: value` pairs.  That is, there's a *single* YAML file as its output, that happens to contain `metadata:` multiple times.  Different tools handle this YAML in different ways, typically either producing an error or by discarding all but the last copy of a given key.  Running `helm template` over your chart will tell you for sure what Helm is generating.

Comment: Running `helm template` generated the file I pasted in my question. I was wondering if there is a way helm will just install all cronjobs with a single command.

Comment: To put this answer differently: if the YAML file you included is accepted by a YAML parser, it only includes one CronJob resource, probably made from the last `metadata:` and `spec:` there.  You either need to split it into three files or explicitly separate it into three documents in the same file.